# asp.net with google chrome in loading images from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Iam retrieving data from database including image links 
,while assigning image sources to returned links and run it , images are not displayed, in page source after drawing links are exist in image sources but not displayed
.
when iam giving its source statically its fine
and in firefox also everything is working fine

that is my code HTML

```
<img runat="server" id="image1" src="/images/carNumberArbil.png" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

C#

```
 var data=(from ads in databaseManager.Ads
                               where ads.AdId.Equals(AdId)
                               select new {
                                AdId=ads.AdId,
                               Title=ads.Title,
                               Price=ads.Price,
                               City=ads.Cities.Name,
                               Category=ads.SubCategories.Categories.Name,
                               SubCategory=ads.SubCategories.Name,
                               Description=ads.Description,
                               PublishedDate=ads.PublishedDate ,
                               Image1=ads.Image1,
                               Image2=ads.Image2,
                               Image3=ads.Image3,
                               Image4=ads.Image4,
                               Image5=ads.Image5
                               }
                                   ).First();




                        this.image1.Src =data.Image1 == null ? "AdImages/AdDefault.png" : "AdImages/" + data.Image1.Substring(0, 7) + data.AdId + "[1]" + data.Image1.Substring(7);
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I put my code for more explanation

Comment: Are you sure that the URL for the image is properly constructed when rendered? If you navigate to the image link can you actually see the picture?

Comment: YES , when I open page-source by Inspect element in Google chrome I can see the URL and navigate it and display it separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem
it was so ridicules,
it was AdBlock plugin in my Google Chrome  preventing my pictures to be shown , but what I still dont understand is why ad block should prevent some images from being displayed by itself !
but at all , my problem solved and my life became easier :)